# Need Pagination on a page Using EntityFieldQuery() to list all nodes of 'Article' content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to show list of all nodes using EntityFieldQuery() with pagination. And i have applied all condition to get my result and it is working fine. But some how pagination not working. I search on google and applied all solutions but its not working. I am getting the result but pagination not displaying. Please Help.

Here is my Code.

```
$output = array();
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type','node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
      ->pager(1);
$results = $query->execute();

if (isset($results['nodes'])) {
         $content = node_view_multiple(node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['nodes'])));
         $output = array(
                     'content'=> $content,
                     'pager'=> array(
                                '#markup' => theme('pager'),
                                '#weight' => 10
                               )
                      );   
}  
print render($output);
```

Thanks,
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

I think the **isset()** should be done on `'node'` instead of `'nodes'`. Same goes for your `$content` var. Instead of `print render($output);` use it as the return value. Like `return $output;`

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type','node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle','article')
    ->pager(1);
$results = $query->execute();
$output = array();
if (isset($results['node'])) {
    $content = node_view_multiple(node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node'])));
    $output = array(
      'content'=> $content,
      'pager'=> array(
          '#markup' => theme('pager'),
          '#weight' => 10
         )
      );   
  }  
  return $output;
```